# .each yields correct class names for .hover call, but not for .css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to build a function that does an opacity fade for CSS objects (.thumbposition1 -> 20). I am dynamically assigning a background image the same CSS properties as its grayscale counterpart, which is being moused over (on a scroller).

This works great when I manually specify each class by name, but when I try to minimize things by introducing an .each call, bad things happen: .hover works fine and returns the CSS class being moused over, but when I go to change (and test) the CSS properties of the overlying and underlying images, the offset values are always the same (top:0px,left:200px).

What am I doing wrong? Please forgive any dumb mistake/hideous code/etc. I am a noob.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("img").each(function(i) {
    var i = i + 1;
    var iString = i.toString();
    var currentThumbPositionString_gs = ".thumbpositiongs" + iString;
    var currentThumbPositionString_c = ".thumbposition" + iString;
    var currentThumb_gs = $(currentThumbPositionString_gs);
    var currentThumb_c = $(currentThumbPositionString_c);
    var thumbPos = currentThumb_gs.offset();
    var thumbPos_c = currentThumb_c.offset();
    currentThumb_gs.hover(function() {  
            currentThumb_c.css({
                    left:thumbPos.left,
                    top:thumbPos.top,
                    height:"auto",
                    width:"auto",
                    "z-index":"-1000000",
                    visibility:"visible"});
            currentThumb_gs.stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "1500");
            },
            function() {
                    currentThumb_gs.stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "1500");
                    currentThumb_c.delay(355).queue( function() {
                    $(currentThumb_c).css({
                    height:"0",
                    width:"0",
                    visibility:"hidden"});
                currentThumb_c.clearQueue();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: using hover within a loop is error-prone.

Comment: So if it works fine when I select each CSS class by name (ie. 20 chunks of code similar to this one), is that an abominable thing to do?

Comment: I mean, it seems like something I ought to be able to do in 30 lines of code or so... but maybe that's just the way it is.

Comment: yes, it selects each class, of course, because `each` is a loop but hover is an event, not an dom element, that's why you end up with one offset value, instead of each try hover alone and it should work as you want. `$('img').hover...`

Comment: I think I've just bitten off more than I can chew. You see, I have a div scroller and I want each image to fade from greyscale to color when you mouse over. My solution was to dynamically assign a background image depending on the location of the greyscale image (which changes with the scroller). So there has to be a one to one relationship between the foreground and background images. Hence, .thumbposition1 through .thumbpositon20. With just .hover, I can't handle each image separately, I think?

Comment: no, plz don't think in that way, your method is fine, it just needs some modifications. as i said just use hover, each is not a good option in this case.

Comment: Does this do what you want it to do? http://jsfiddle.net/Nyjbr/1/

Comment: I think it has something to do with var i = i + 1; make it var j = i+1